# How to create/read a node bilingualy

Tags: alfresco

I need to create nodes with bilingual properties, and use all of these nodes as (List constraints) where node property will be label and another property will be value.

So, is this doable ? & how ?

I see sys:localized, and its mean
Localization:
         If you add this aspect to a node, then the server will assume that all non-multilingual
         properties apply to this locale.
can this help me !

Thanks
Mohammed Amr
Senior System Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to [handle Multi Lingual documents](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/tasks/tuh-multilingual.html) from your code you are supposed to use the [MultilingualContentService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/ml/MultilingualContentService.html) to:

- [add](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/ml/MultilingualContentService.html#addTranslation%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20java.util.Locale%29) a translation
- [retrieve](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/ml/MultilingualContentService.html#getTranslations%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef%29) the available translations
- etc.

Multilingual documents have the `cm:mlDocument` aspect applied. This enables them to be listed as children of the special `cm:mlContainer` that's created under `/cm:multilingualRoot` to track translations of a single document. The `cm:mlContainer` is defined as follows:

```
  <type name="cm:mlContainer">
     <title>Multilingual Container</title>
     <parent>sys:container</parent>
     <associations>
        <child-association name="cm:mlChild">
           <source>
              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
              <many>false</many>
           </source>
           <target>
              <class>cm:mlDocument</class>
              <mandatory>true</mandatory>
              <many>true</many>
           </target>
        </child-association>
     </associations>
     <mandatory-aspects>
        <aspect>cm:versionable</aspect>
        <aspect>cm:author</aspect>
        <aspect>sys:localized</aspect>
     </mandatory-aspects>
  </type>
```

Comment: Thanks skuro, but listen What i need to do is to create a nodes and use them again (use a certain property of those nodes) as a list of values (i.e constraints list values) and the node properties needs to be bilingual that what i mean by my question. How to create a node and make its properties bilingual to use it again as a list of constraints ?

Comment: What about sys:localized Skuro !

Answer (score 2):

There are different kinds of localization options in Alfresco:

- The MultilingualContentService (with the cm:mlDocument aspect) allows you to store translated **content** on a single node. You can use this if you have a document that is translated into multiple languages. There is no support for this in Share but you can use it via the Alfresco Explorer or the API.
- There are also multilingual text **properties**. You can use the datatype *d:mlText* in your content model and to store property values (strings only) based on the user language. The build in properties *cm:title* and *cm:description* are of type *d:mlText*. The usage in Share is a bit tricky though - Alfresco uses the browser language to automatically choose the locale, so users with different browser languages will see different values.

As far as I understand your question, I think what you need are the *ml:properties*. The Share UI only supports them indirectly, maybe that's ok for you. As for the the List constraints I have not seen any multi language support there, so you probably have to extend those yourself.