# Multilingual documents in Alfresco Share?

Tags: multilingual, alfresco

Alfresco has a [MultilingualContentService](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/tasks/tuh-multilingual.html) but unfortunately [it is not implemented in the Share UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482983#7482983).

So, how to handle mutilingual content in Share?
(for each document, several files in different languages)

Is there some solution ready?
If I have no choice but to develop, how would you do it?

Comment: Have you looked at how the WCM QuickStart in Alfresco 4.0 does multilingual content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in an object that's accessible from your webscripts. [Here's an example](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=14587#p47953) which already does it:

```
package com.someco.web.jscript;

import org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptNode;
import org.alfresco.repo.processor.BaseProcessorExtension;
import org.alfresco.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.ml.MultilingualContentService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.util.Locale;

public final class MultilingualScript extends BaseProcessorExtension
{
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MultilingualScript.class);

   private MultilingualContentService multilingualContentService;
   private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

   public MultilingualScript()
   {
      if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
         logger.debug("MultilingualScript Constructor Called");
      }
   }   

   //path = path of the original document
   //language = required language
   //returns the noderef for the translation content for the given language   
   public ScriptNode multilingualContent(String path, String language, ScriptNode companyHome) {
      if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
         logger.debug("MultilingualScript - parameters - " + path + " , " + language);
      }
      NodeRef nodeRef =  new ScriptNode(companyHome.getNodeRef(), serviceRegistry)
         .childByNamePath(path).getNodeRef();      
      nodeRef = multilingualContentService.getTranslationForLocale(nodeRef, new Locale(language) );      
      return new ScriptNode(nodeRef, serviceRegistry);
   }

   public MultilingualContentService getMultilingualContentService() {
      return multilingualContentService;
   }

   public void setMultilingualContentService(
         MultilingualContentService multilingualContentService) {
      this.multilingualContentService = multilingualContentService;
   }

   public ServiceRegistry getServiceRegistry() {
      return serviceRegistry;
   }

   public void setServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
      this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
   }
}
```

The Spring bean:

```
<bean id="multilingualScript" parent="baseJavaScriptExtension" class="com.someco.web.jscript.MultilingualScript">
       <property name="extensionName">
           <value>multilingual</value>
       </property>
      <property name="serviceRegistry">
         <ref bean="ServiceRegistry" />
      </property>
      <property name="multilingualContentService">
         <ref bean="MultilingualContentService" />
      </property>
   </bean>
```

And finally, use it like this:

```
var multilingualArticle = multilingual.multilingualContent("/myarticle", "es", companyhome);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess showing the actual content shouldn't be to hard, because every content has his own uuid.
The difficulty will be in creating a UI to upload a different language.

The first thing I would do is analyze how the action 'upload new version' works. 
So what we need is a custom action to upload a different language file and a popup to select which language that is. So the 'upload new version' does almost exactly the same, you can browse to a file and fill in versioning comment.

I don't know if there are webscripts available in Explorer to store the multilingual content, if not you should develop those.

Secondly is to create a webscript to return you all the multilingual files (same as above, probably won't exist)

Then define a block, like the workflows or version block, so links will appear of the files.