# Multilingual document name and metadata for unique Alfresco Share document (same data content)

Tags: alfresco, multilingual, alfresco-share

For the same document in Alfresco Share, I want the name and some metadata to be shown differently depending on the user's language.

Here is the standard metadata edition screen in Alfresco Share:

[image: Alfresco metadata]

I would like the title field to have a dropdown to choose for instance "French" that would allow me to type "Galaxie Andromède", and that label would then be shown to francophone users viewing that document.

It would be great to be able to do the same for the description and other prose fields too. Of course, I don't need this for non-prose fields like the Mimetype.

I guess this feature is not available in Alfresco Share without some custom development?
But are there building bricks that I could use to make that development efficient and well in the spirit of Alfresco?

*Note: Only one content file, for all languages. This is very different from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850401/multilingual-documents-in-alfresco-share), in which a single entity has a content file for each language.*

Comment: Nicolas, take a look to https://github.com/loftuxab/alfresco-community-loftux/issues/5 and https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-11198 and be aware that the protocol adapters only stores in the default locale.

Answer (score 2):

Multilingual properties (of type ml:text in the Alfresco model) are already displayed in the user language based on the browser locale.

So if the user browser is in French he will see and update the French value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

Anything other than "cm:title" or "cm:description" will require at least some modifications.

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5111-multilingual-document-support